# How will open-circuit voltage affect the Fermi Level Difference

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, solid-state-physics, electrons, electronics

The circumstances of my question consists of this: I have two materials, copper and cesium, and they are sandwiched together with a layer of cesium in the middle. It is connected only on a single side to another circuit system, thus making the copper-cesium sandwich itself an incomplete circuit. My question is how would the open-circuit potential affect the Fermi Level of either material, if at all?  Here are the Fermi Energy values which may be relevant: Copper: 7.0eV; Cesium: 1.59eV.

Comment: This is not specific enough to answer. What materials? What are the Fermi-levels locations? When materials come into contact the Fermi-levels align until a space charge halts any further change.

Answer (score 1):

It is not affected at all. There is no net potential difference across the sandwich whether it is part of a circuit or not.